# Broadcast Receiving

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-screen

My problem is that my application simply finishes when the screen turns off. I think I have to override the broadcast receiving methods and register them. But I don't know what to do when the ACTION_SCREEN_OFF event occurs to show the application in the same state when the screen turns on again. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to do anything at all to remain in a given state between SCREEN_OFF and SCREEN_ON -- unless your code is doing something to disrupt that state in its lifecycle methods (such as `onPause()`). If you call `finish()` in your onPause() method (as your question loosely suggests), stop doing that.

Answer (score 0):

BroadcastReceivers aren't important to you.
Maybe you did handle `onPause()` or `onDestroy()` wrong in your Activity.

See 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ProcessLifecycle

For further information regarding the activity lifecycle